# What is the value of $ a_{2009}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the following sequence :

$a_0 = 3 $

$ a_n = 2 + a_0 a_1 a_2\text{ ...}a_{n-1} $

How can I find the value of $a_{2009} $ ?

Comment: HINT: $a_{n+1}=a_n(a_n-2)+2$

Comment: I have find this relation . But after that I cant proceed

Comment: @LeeNeverGup, how did you find this relation?

Comment: @Sush Hint: It's immediate from the recurrence relation (subtract 2, from it, to begin with)

Comment: @Sush $a_n-2=a_0a_1...a_{n-1}$. Then $a_n(a_n-2)+2=a_0a_1...a_{n-1}a_n+2=a_{n+1}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rewrite $a_{n+1} = a_n(a_n-2) + 2$ as $a_{n+1} - 1 = (a_n -1)^2$

To clarify further.

If $b_n = a_n -1$, then we have $b_{n+1} = (b_n)^2$, and so $b_{n} = (b_0)^{2^n}$.

Comment: And then put $b_n=a_n-1$?

Comment: @LeeNeverGup: Yes...

Comment: @Aryabhata, how did you derive from $b_{n+1} = (b_n)^2$ the $b_{n} = (b_0)^{2^n}$?

Comment: @Sush: induction

Comment: @arbautjc, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

First, you can prove $a_{n+1}=a_n(a_n-2)+2$, this way:

The recurrence formula gives you

$$a_n-2=a_0a_1...a_{n-1}$$

Thus, multiplying by $a_n$,

$$a_n(a_n-2)=a_0a_1...a_n=a_{n+1}-2$$

Then, you can prove $a_n=2^{2^n}+1$ (that is, they are [Fermat numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number)), by induction.

It's true for $a_0=3=2^{2^0}+1$.

If it's true for $a_n$, then

$$a_{n+1}=a_n(a_n-2)+2=\left(2^{2^n}+1\right) \left(2^{2^n}-1\right) + 2$$
$$=2^{2^n\cdot 2}-1+2=2^{2^{n+1}}+1$$

Hence it's true for all $n$.

Note: you can deduce immediately that Fermat numbers are coprime to each other, using the recurrence formula. Indeed, it proves that a common divisor of $a_n$ and $a_k$ for $k<n$, must be also a divisor of $2$, thus it's $1$, since they are odd.

Comment: Your answer is too much good . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{aligned} 
 a_0 &= 3\\
 a_1 &= 2 + a_0 = 2 + 3\\ 
 a_2 &= 2 + a_1 a_0 = 2 + ( 2 + a_0)a_0 = 2 + 2a_0 +a_0^2\overset{a_0 = 3}{=}2+ 2\cdot 3 +3^2\\ 
 a_3 &= 2 + a_2 a_1 a_0 = \dots = 2 + ( 2+ (2 +a_0)a_0)a_0 \\&= 
2 + 2 a_0 + 2 a_0^2 + a_0^3 \overset{a_0 = 3}{=} 2 + 2 \cdot 3 + 2 \cdot 3^2 + 3^3 \overset{(*)}{=} 2\sum_{k=0}^2 3^k+3^3 \end{aligned}$$
Look at the last equation marked with the asterisk $(*)$.
 Think of a formula for induction... I'll leave this to you. Shouldn't be hard ;).
To be more precise:
$$a_3 = 2\sum_{k=0}^2 3^k+3^3$$
and analogous equations should hold for $a_n,\,n\geq 1$.
The inductive proof will follow easily if you look at the mapping $x\in\mathbb{R}\mapsto f(x):=2 + x 3$, because as you can see above, for $n\geq1$, $a_n$ has a form easily expressed with $f$.

Very late edit:
Once you have proven the analogous formula, getting $a_{2009}$ is as simple as pasting into the formula and calculating the result.